# Generate a unique numeric String based off another String iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, security, random

I'm looking to generate a unique string of numbers - preferabley 6-8 digits long, based off another string.

e.g. I have a string containing an email address. Then when clicking a button i get another string containing a unique 6-8 digit number based off of that email address.

Comment: do MD5 encryption or SHA 256. It will be a bit long but will be unique.

Comment: @PranjalBikashDas Such hashes are not guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: What is this used for? If you provide details, we may be able to provide a better (read standard) method. @rmaddy, if you can find a collision with SHA 2, you will be the first.

Comment: @rmaddy collisions for SHA 2 is none and so it happens to be unique. You can go through the link for reference
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The others suggested using a cryptographically secure MD5 hash.

If you don't care about cryptographic security, you could also simply use the built-in hash function:

```
NSUInteger *emailHash = [emailAddressString hash];
```

Since what you're converting to a number is an email address, it seems like encryption is overkill.

Comment: +1 for making life easier for the OP. As for your concerns about cryptography: this hash is as _cryptographic_ as MD5. No more no less. Hash can't be decrypted back to original string. You could though generate a set of strings that generate that same hash.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an MD5 hash.

[H2CO3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/529758/h2co3) published a category for this: [NSString-MD5](https://github.com/H2CO3/NSString-MD5)

You will have to `#import "NSString-MD5"`.

Then you can create a hash:

```
NSString *emailHash = [email MD5Hash];
```

License is, well, public domain.

As rmaddy pointed out: there are no guarantees that you will get absolutely unique value which goes for any hashing method with fixed result size (ie: limited number of results for unlimited number of input variants).

Comment: While the odds of a collision are tiny, an MD5 hash is not guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: That is absolutely true. But it is the same for any other hashing method.

Comment: Wouldn't including an encryption library mean that you had to check the "does this program include encryption" checkbox, and potentially restrict non-US distribution of the resulting app?

Comment: In that case every app that sends MD5 hashed password instead of a raw one would have to have this checkbox ticked. And also every app that uses SSL connection. And every app that uses Stripe for example.

Answer (score 1):

Create an md5 hash on the string. CC_MD5 return 16 bytes. If you want to take 8 bytes, you can discard other bytes, but you need to check for uniqueness, (compare with your earlier received or stored values).

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonHMAC.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>


+ (NSString *)md5String:(NSString *)plainText
{
    if(plainText == nil || [plainText length] == 0)
        return nil;

    const char *value = [plainText UTF8String];
    unsigned char outputBuffer[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_MD5(value, strlen(value), outputBuffer);

    NSMutableString *outputString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];
    for(NSInteger count = 0; count < CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; count++){
        [outputString appendFormat:@"%02x",outputBuffer[count]];
    }
    NSString * retString = [NSString stringWithString:outputString];
    [outputString release];
    return retString;
}
```